# Initial field of expression must be concrete Sobject

Tags: apex, trigger

```
`trigger AccountReplicate on Account (after delete, after insert, after update) {

 if(trigger.isInsert)
 {
 for (Account acc:trigger.new)
{
    AccountOne__c ac = new AccountOne__c();
    ac.Fax__c = acc.Fax;
    ac.Phone__c = acc.Phone;
    ac.Name =acc.Name;
    insert ac;
}
    }`


  if(trigger.isUpdate)
   {
   AccountOne__c[] a2 = [Select Id from AccountOne__c where Name =:   trigger.old.Name];    
  for(AccountOne__c c1 : a2)
  { 
    c1.Name=trigger.new.Name;
    c1.Fax__C =trigger.new.Fax;
    c1.Phone__C=trigger.new.Phone;
  }

  update a2;
}
```

When I try this code I get `initial field of expression must be concrete sobject` error.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Manoj, can you share more of the trigge and which line is causing the error?

Comment: AccountOne__c[] a2 = [Select Id from AccountOne__c where Name =: trigger.old.Name];  this line

Comment: i have posted my full code

Answer (score 4):

The problem potentially lies in this line, where you're trying to access the Name field on a trigger.old collection

```
Select Id from AccountOne__c where Name =:   trigger.old.Name
```

You would have to aggregate all Names from trigger.old and then perform the comparison

So

```
List<String> names = new List<String>{};
For(Account acc : trigger.old)
names.add(acc.name);
AccountOne__c[] a2 = [Select Id from AccountOne__c where Name IN :names];
```

Comment: how would i update with new name after this

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat unrelated (but I can't yet comment):

You should avoid DML operations inside a for loop. So instead of:

```
for (Account acc:trigger.new)
{
    AccountOne__c ac = new AccountOne__c();
    ac.Fax__c = acc.Fax;
    ac.Phone__c = acc.Phone;
    ac.Name =acc.Name;
    insert ac;
}
```

Do this:

```
List<Account> accountsToInsert = new List<Account>();
for (Account acc:trigger.new)
{
    AccountOne__c ac = new AccountOne__c();
    ac.Fax__c = acc.Fax;
    ac.Phone__c = acc.Phone;
    ac.Name =acc.Name;
    accountsToInsert.add(ac);
}
insert accountsToInsert;
```

Now it's bulk safe.

Answer (score 1):

Just to specifically answer the original question...the error you posted about is because trigger.new and trigger.old are lists - so you can't reference it like this:

```
trigger.new.Name
```

With a list, it has to be by position to avoid that particular error e.g.

```
c1.Name = trigger.new[0].Name; //which is an item in the list, so an actual record
```

or like in answer 1, by iterating over the list. Hard coding in the position for trigger.new is not to be recommended though, since as other posts point out, that is not bulk friendly.

But if you combine answer 1 & 2, you would be most of the way there to getting to work as you 
want I think...